# Direct Write: GetFontFamilyName returning different results every time

Tags: c++, directx, 2d

Am Creating this function to return the Font Family Name but obviously it seems to be pointing on different results every time:

```
unsigned int len = txtFormat->GetFontFamilyNameLength();
WCHAR fontFamilyName[64];
txtFormat->GetFontFamilyName(fontFamilyName, len+1);
//fontFamilyName[len] = '\0'; not needed because the function "GetFontFamilyName" returns a null terminated pointer.
return fontFamilyName;
```

Comment: According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316636(v=vs.85).aspx), the result you get back is already null terminated.  There's some example code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd941712(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  Specify the output you are getting.  Did you check out those links I posted?

Comment: Thanks Robert, I solved the problem this afternoon. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
txtFormat->GetFontFamilyName(fontFamilyName, len+1);
```

to:

```
txtFormat->GetFontFamilyName(fontFamilyName, sizeof(fontFamilyName)/sizeof(fontFamilyName[0]));
```

This will make sure that GetFontFamilyName doesn't overrun the buffer that you're passing in.

Answer (score 0):

it took me a bit longer than needed but I got it right now.

The reason is that creating array with [] will not return the correct address. so we can have two solutions:

Solution 1: Dynamically locate an array to return within the function. remember to delete the returned text once done with it.

```
inline WCHAR *GetFontFamilyName(IDWriteTextFormat *txtFormat)
{
    WCHAR *fontFamilyName = new WCHAR[64];
    unsigned int len = txtFormat->GetFontFamilyNameLength();
    txtFormat->GetFontFamilyName(fontFamilyName, len+1);
    //fontFamilyName[len] = L'\0'; not really needed but it can be used as confirmation
    return fontFamilyName;
}
```

Solution 2: Pass a static array to the function. in this case you will not have to delete it because, it is not dynamically allocated.

in this case, you can pass an array such as name[64] to the function and you will not have to worry about deleting the text.

```
inline void GetFontFamilyName(IDWriteTextFormat *txtFormat, WCHAR fontFamilyName [])
{
    unsigned int len = txtFormat->GetFontFamilyNameLength();
    txtFormat->GetFontFamilyName(fontFamilyName, len+1);
//fontFamilyName[len] = L'\0'; not really needed but it can be used as confirmation.
}
```